# Normalize to scale

Tags: math, normalize

I have an 2-D array of data (**C**), where **C(:,1)** has values corresponding to **C(:,2)**. **C(:,2)** varies from 0.0001:0.0001:1, i.e. 10,000 values. I need to calculate the **d(log(C(i,1))) / d(log(C(i,2)))**, which I do by simply calculating **log(C(i,1)) / log(C(i,2))**. But as C(i,2), approaches 1, the denominator approaches zero, and the quotient shoots up. One way to keep this in check would be to normalize it using a parameter, but I'm not sure how to do that. Does anyone have an idea about this?

Comment: You want to calculate the quotient... but not if the quotient is too big... so you want to perform some other calculation instead. *what are you actually trying to do?*

Comment: I actually want to plot this quotient, i.e. the slope  **d(log(C(i,1))) / d(log(C(i,2)))** vs log(C(:,2)), and as C(i,2) approaches 1, the slope should converge to zero, to be able to study it.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is discrete differentiation, the answer is bound to be a little inelegant.

You're interested in the derivative d(log(C(i,1))) / d(log(C(i,2)))

```
=∆(log(C(i,1))) / ∆(log(C(i,2)))

=(log(C(i+1,1))-log(C(i,1))) / (log(C(i,2)) - log(C(i,2)))
```

which is tractable. The denominator does not go to zero, it goes to the step size (0.0001).